# Google Now is not able to call one of my Google contacts

Tags: contacts, calls, google-now

Google Now can call all of my contacts... except for one: James P*****. See the following screenshot:

[image: call james p*****]
<sup>Screenshot: Call James (click image for larger variant)</sup>

What? Who the hell is James A. Kellam? An attorney, apparently, but I don't know him.

Let's try a similar name, also in my contacts: Jimmy P***** (same last name, different contact):

[image: call jimmy p*****]
<sup>Screenshot: Call Jimmy (click image for larger variant)</sup>

As you can see, that works as expected. I find this strange because they are both Google contacts. They both show up on `http://contacts.google.com` and they are both marked as Google contacts on my phone.

Why can't I call James through Google Now, but I can call Jimmy?

I am running CyanogenMod 10.0.0-d2vzw on a Samsung Galaxy S III.

Comment: Is the voice recognition correctly getting the last name you are saying? I can never get it to understand my last name, so it usually does a google search for what I thought it said, instead of trying to call a contact.

Comment: Yes, I blacked it out but the last name is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have several contacts that act the same way. Sometimes when I append the contact's number's label to the end of my spoken command it helps; something like, "Call John Smith, mobile" or "Call John Smith, home."

Comment: "Call James P\*\*\*\*\*, Mobile" just comes up with "Contact not found." There is an option for "find contact." I press that and select "James P\*\*\*\*\*" and then press mobile and it calls. If I say "Call James P\*\*\*\*\*, Mobile" again, however, it just comes up with the same "Contact not found" screen.

Comment: Does adding "on" help? E.g., "Call John Smith on mobile"

Comment: Adding on did fix it. Strange.

Comment: Strange indeed. I only do it as a hold-over from a previous phone that required voice commands be given in a specific way. I'm glad it helped solve your trouble.

Comment: It gets stranger: "Call James" works now but not "Call James P\*\*\*\*\*."